# TCPDF serializeTCPDFtagParameters

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I need to place barcodes inside html tables,  and TCPDF gives the answer in example 49.

However if I use the same code in a plain test.php file:

```
$params = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('CODE 128', 'C128', '', '', 80, 30, 0.4, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>true, 'padding'=>4, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>8, 'stretchtext'=>4), 'N'));

$html .= '<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="'.$params.'" />';
```

No barcode is rendered.  But if instead I use this method:

```
 $pdf->write2DBarcode('www.tcpdf.org', 'PDF417', 80, 90, 0, 30, $style, 'N');.
```

I get the expected barcode.

Clearly there is no problem with fonts, and other stuff.

I copy and uploaded to my server the tcpdf folder,  including the /examples/ folder.  If I call to exmaple 49 inside the examples folder:

```
/mywebsite/tcpdf/examples/example_049.php
```

it works perfect,  renders the barcodes as expected.

However if I render the same example from other location:

```
 /mywebsite/example_049.php
```

The generated pdf lacks of the barcodes, but renders text, headers, logos, and other stuff.  Indeed renders a barcode generated by the **write2DBarcode()** method.

Yes I updated the required files,  from the original included in the example **tcpdf_include.php** to **tcpdf/tcpdf.php**.

Any help is welcome,  If somebody know how to ask directly to Mr. Asuni or the TCPDF staff,  also welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue after upgrading to a newer version of TCPDF.

By default, the `K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML` constant is set to `FALSE` in the config file **config/tcpdf_config.php**, preventing the use of the `<tcpdf>` tag.

As a quick test, try changing this value to `TRUE` in the config, and see if your tag renders as expected. You can then look into overriding this config value correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Alan Lapington,  atn the end I gave up with TCPDF and went with MPDF.  Less overhead and even quicker and less server stress.

Comment: How do we override this value `K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML = true` in our custom file.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to override in all files you can define it like:

```
define('K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML', true);
```